# Import tiff + tfw + prj files in R

Tags: r, tiff, rgdal

I want to import in R a map that I have downloaded from

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-natural-earth-1/

When I download it I get 3 files with the following extension

```
.tif
.tfw
.prj
```

How should I read them? I can read the .tif file with

```
 imported_raster=raster('NE1_HR_LC_SR_W.tif')
```

but then the colours and the projection are different from the original tif.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for some information on another topic when I came across this one.

1. It's quite normal that the colours appear different from the original tif. There probably was a color distribution or a colour scheme applied on the original tif which isn't exported to or with the output tif. It's the user that should set a colour scheme or color distribution. (Just like in arcmap for example).
2. I guess your exported tif has no projection at all when you load it in R? You need to use the information from the .tfw file to give each pixel (row, column) a coordinate.
   Read in the .tfw file
   Assume that your .tfw (ascii file) is something like this:
   10.000000
   0.000000000000000
   0.000000000000000
   -10.000000000000
   137184.00000000000
   180631.000000000
   The last two rows are the X/Y coordinates of the center of the upperleft pixel of your tif.
   The first row tells you what your spatial resolution is, in this case 10.

So if you know the coordinate of the center of the upper pixel, than the coordinate of pixel (row=i, column=j) is
137184+i*10, 180631+i*10).